# How to show that solution of DE does not exceed $m$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I need to show that a DE $x' +cx = g(t)$ for positive $c$ and bounded function $g \in C(\mathbb{R})$ has a unique bounded solution. My attempt: I wanted to find the solutions, so I multiply the equation by $ e^{\int cdt}=e^{ct}$ such that it becomes $(e^{ct}x)' = e^{ct}g(t) $. It follows, $ \quad x = \frac{\int e^{ct}g(t)dt}{e^ct} \quad$ and I guess the integral can be calculated by solving it by parts. However, I'm not sure that it would really help. Anyway, it would not show why such a bounded solution is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always encourage students to write the solution with the actual limits of integration; I think that will make this clearer. From $$\Big( e^{ct} x(t) \Big)' = e^{ct} g(t),$$ integrate the equation from $0$ up to some $t$: $$\int^t_0 \Big(e^{cs}x(s)\Big)'ds = \int^t_0 e^{cs}g(s)ds \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\, e^{ct}x(t) - x(0) = \int^t_0 e^{cs}g(s)ds.$$ Note, this is the same as your solution, just for you the constant $x(0)$ is hidden in the integral $\int e^{ct}g(t)dt$. Continuing, $$x(t) = x(0)e^{-ct} + e^{-ct}\int^t_0e^{cs}g(s)ds.$$ You've assumed $g$ is bounded; say $\lvert g(s) \rvert \le M$ for all $s \in \mathbb R$. Then \begin{align*} \lvert x(t) \rvert &\le \lvert x(0) \rvert e^{-ct} + e^{-ct}\int^t_0M e^{cs}ds \\ 
&\le \lvert x(0)\rvert e^{-ct} + Me^{-ct}\frac{1}{c}(e^{ct}-1) \\ 
&= \lvert x(0) \rvert e^{-ct} + \frac M c(1-e^{-ct})
\end{align*}

Note that $0 \le e^{-ct} \le 1$ when $c,t \ge 0$ and thus we also have $0 \le 1-e^{-ct} \le 1$. Using both these bounds, we arrive at $$\lvert x(t) \rvert \le \lvert x(0) \rvert + \frac M c$$ which shows that $x$ remains bounded.

Note: I've assumed you are only considering $t \ge 0$. If you are also considering solutions for $t \in \mathbb R$, then the property isn't true, as can easily be seen with an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, $t$ is any real number.

Comment: @student In that case, take $g \equiv 0$ and the solution is $x(t) = x(0)e^{-ct}$ which is unbounded as $t \to -\infty$ whenever $x(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: How can I confirm the uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: This bound gives uniqueness after you've specified an initial condition. If $x(t), y(t)$ are two solutions such that $x(0) = y(0)$, then the difference $u(t) = x(t) - y(t)$ satisfies $u'+cu = 0$ which is the same equation with $g \equiv 0$. Thus you can use the same bound but with $M = 0$, and you have $$\lvert u(t) \rvert \le \lvert u(0) \rvert e^{-ct}.$$ But $u(0) = 0$ and so $u(t) = 0$ for all $t$ which gives $x(t) = y(t)$. [Of course, there is nothing special about $0$; the value could be specified somewhere else you could re-establish the bound near that point.]